# SharePoint list calculated column formula not working

Tags: sharepoint-2010, listitem, calculated-columns

I have a calculated column named "Link" which is used to show the link (url) of a particular list item. The formula in the calculated column adds/appends the value in the ID column. The formula works for existing items, However when new items are added the calculated column does not contain the value of the ID column. However if I go to the settings of the "Link" calculated column re-write the formula the Click OK the, the formala works  and adds the value of the ID column to most recent list item. The problem starts again when a new list item is added in that the value of the ID column is not added and again I ma having to keep going to the "Link" calculated column settings and again re-write the formula.

The formula is the following:

="http://www.sampleweb.com/articles/item.aspx?ListName=Articles%20Bytes&ID="&ID

and the results it produced are the following:

http://www.sampleweb.co.uk/articles/item.aspx?ListName=Articles%20Bytes&ID=44

but again when a new item is added the following is displayed

http://www.sampleweb.co.uk/articles/item.aspx?ListName=Articles%20Bytes&ID=

Does any one have any suggestions as to why the formula does not work when new list items and /or how to resolve it.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar problem with workflow workaround. It's helpful to use workflow also for later calculation of calculated values...

Comment: Even I am facing similar problem and I am looking for any help. @Martin - Is it possible for for you to share the Workflow workaround?